# Проверка изменений на сервере

Tags: клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте. Не подскажете, кроме как по таймеру проверять аяксом, никак нельзя узнать об изменениях на сервере (в БД)?

Делаем систему для диспетчеров - рабочий стол на ExtJS и полностью на аяксе. На главной обычные пользователи будут оставлять заявки и хотелось бы сразу уведомить всплывающим сообщением. Но эти заявки будут очень редкими, поэтому таймер - нецелесообразно.

П.С. Где-то читал о запросах, ответ на которые приходит при появлении ответа. Типа запрос послал, а ответ придет когда изменится. (Мне это приснилось?)

Приходит в голову по 1 вариант (вместе должно дать эффект):
 1. При загрузке с сервера проверяется наличие новых заявок.
 2. В каждом ответе сервера (по любому запросу) добавлять в конец например: "is_new_request": true/false и при каждой обработке ответа проверять.

П.П.С. APACHE+PHP

Comment: Для этого есть технологии
WebSocket или Long Polling

Comment: А у Вас есть возможность запустить php как демон, без ограничений на время исполнения?

Comment: @brute, а apache+php такое умеет? Или такое умеют "особые" сервера?  
П.С. В любом случае спасибо. Теперь знаю куда копать.

Comment: @ReinRaus, сомневаюсь, что хостер это позволит.

Comment: Apache такое не поддерживается, для этого нужно запускать отдельные процессы php, например 
Dklab Realplexor  для Long Polling или Ratchet для вебсокетов, также есть phpDaemon, он поддерживает обе технологии.